# Unity3D moving with Character Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm having a capsule with a Character Controller component implemented. To move it I'm using:

```
public float player_speed=0.6f;
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
    this.GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(new Vector3(transform.forward.x*player_speed,0f,transform.forward.z*player_speed));
}
```

But when I set the value of `player_speed` to 0.3f, it starts flying. I don't know why.
Could somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html take note of the Time.deltaTime

Answer (score 0):

Character Controller does not automatically add gravity, so you'll need to implement that yourself. The simplest way to do this is usually to keep gravity at 0 (or a small number) if the character is grounded, and then if he's not grounded, gradually increase the gravity strength (up to a maximum).

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion the OP doesn't actually mean "flying", but rather that the controller moves at an incredible speed. Which I'd say is caused by not taking deltaTime into account.

Comment: Nvm, thank you for help i fixed th issue i had. PS: I have gravity implemented.

Comment: If you fixed the issue, perhaps add an answer on how you did so @user2377766.